# Node.js formidable file upload working slow on server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, nginx, pm2

I am trying to send files as form data along with some fields using http post request in angular.js and receiving file in app.post in node.js. The file sending works fine on localhost. As they say formidable uploads files at 500 mb/sec speed but on server when I am trying to send a file of 5 to 10 mb it takes 40 to 80 seconds. Please check is there any problem in my implementation.
I am using nginx and pm2 on server.

Node.js code:

```
// route for uploading audio asynchronously
app.post('/v1/uploadAudio', function(req, res) {
    var userName, useravatar, hasfile, ismusicfile, isType, showMe, DWimgsrc, DWid, msgtime;
    var imgdatetimenow = Date.now();
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm({
        uploadDir: __dirname + '/public/app/upload/music',
        keepExtensions: true
    });


    form.on('end', function() {
        res.end();
    });
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        console.log("files : ", files);
        console.log("fields : ", fields);
        var data = {
            username: fields.username,
            userAvatar: fields.userAvatar,
            repeatMsg: true,
            hasFile: fields.hasFile,
            isMusicFile: fields.isMusicFile,
            istype: fields.istype,
            showme: fields.showme,
            dwimgsrc: fields.dwimgsrc,
            dwid: fields.dwid,
            serverfilename: baseName(files.file.path),
            msgTime: fields.msgTime,
            filename: files.file.name,
            size: bytesToSize(files.file.size)
        };
        var audio_file = {
            dwid: fields.dwid,
            filename: files.file.name,
            filetype: fields.istype,
            serverfilename: baseName(files.file.path),
            serverfilepath: files.file.path,
            expirytime: imgdatetimenow + (120000)
        };
        files_array.push(audio_file);
        ios.sockets.emit('new message music', data);
    });
});
```

AngularJS code:

```
// =========================================== Audio Sending Code =====================
$scope.$watch('musicFiles', function() {
    $scope.sendAudio($scope.musicFiles);
});

//  opens the sent music file on music_icon click on new window
$scope.openClickMusic = function(msg) {
    $http.post($rootScope.baseUrl + "/v1/getfile", msg).success(function(response) {
        if (!response.isExpired) {
            window.open($rootScope.baseUrl + '/' + response.serverfilename, "_blank");
        } else {
            var html = '<p id="alert">' + response.expmsg + '</p>';
            if ($(".chat-box").has("p").length < 1) {
                $(html).hide().prependTo(".chat-box").fadeIn(1500);
                $('#alert').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $('#alert').remove();
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

// recieving new music message
$socket.on("new message music", function(data) {
    if (data.username == $rootScope.username) {
        data.ownMsg = true;
        data.dwimgsrc = "app/images/spin.gif";
    } else {
        data.ownMsg = false;
    }
    if ((data.username == $rootScope.username) && data.repeatMsg) {
        checkMessegesMusic(data);
    } else {
        $scope.messeges.push(data);
    }
});

// replacing spinning wheel in sender message after music message delivered to everyone.
function checkMessegesMusic(msg) {
    for (var i = ($scope.messeges.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        if ($scope.messeges[i].hasFile) {
            if ($scope.messeges[i].istype === "music") {
                if ($scope.messeges[i].dwid === msg.dwid) {
                    $scope.messeges[i].showme = true;
                    $scope.messeges[i].serverfilename = msg.serverfilename;
                    $scope.messeges[i].filename = msg.filename;
                    $scope.messeges[i].size = msg.size;
                    $scope.messeges[i].dwimgsrc = "app/images/musicplay_icon.png";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

// download music file if it exists on server else return error message
$scope.downloadMusic = function(ev, elem) {
    var search_id = elem.id;
    for (var i = ($scope.messeges.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        if ($scope.messeges[i].hasFile) {
            if ($scope.messeges[i].istype === "music") {
                if ($scope.messeges[i].dwid === search_id) {
                    $http.post($rootScope.baseUrl + "/v1/getfile", $scope.messeges[i]).success(function(response) {
                        if (!response.isExpired) {
                            var linkID = "#" + search_id + "A";
                            $(linkID).find('i').click();
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            var html = '<p id="alert">' + response.expmsg + '</p>';
                            if ($(".chat-box").has("p").length < 1) {
                                $(html).hide().prependTo(".chat-box").fadeIn(1500);
                                $('#alert').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
                                    $('#alert').remove();
                                });
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

// validate file type to 'music file' function
$scope.validateMP3 = function(file) {
    if (file.type == "audio/mp3" || file.type == "audio/mpeg") {
        return true;
    } else {
        var html = '<p id="alert">Select MP3.</p>';
        if ($(".chat-box").has("p").length < 1) {
            $(html).hide().prependTo(".chat-box").fadeIn(1500);
            $('#alert').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $('#alert').remove();
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
}

// sending new 'music file' function
$scope.sendAudio = function(files) {
    if (files && files.length) {
        $scope.isFileSelected = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            var dateString = formatAMPM(new Date());
            var DWid = $rootScope.username + "dwid" + Date.now();
            var audio = {
                username: $rootScope.username,
                userAvatar: $rootScope.userAvatar,
                hasFile: $scope.isFileSelected,
                isMusicFile: true,
                istype: "music",
                showme: false,
                dwimgsrc: "app/images/musicplay_icon.png",
                dwid: DWid,
                msgTime: dateString
            }

            $socket.emit('send-message', audio, function(data) { // sending new image message via socket
            });
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);
            fd.append('username', $rootScope.username);
            fd.append('userAvatar', $rootScope.userAvatar);
            fd.append('hasFile', $scope.isFileSelected);
            fd.append('isMusicFile', true);
            fd.append('istype', "music");
            fd.append('showme', false);
            fd.append('dwimgsrc', "app/images/musicplay_icon.png");
            fd.append('dwid', DWid);
            fd.append('msgTime', dateString);
            fd.append('filename', file.name);
            $http.post('/v1/uploadAudio', fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': undefined
                }
            }).then(function(response) {
                // console.log(response);
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I've used Formidable on a couple of side projects, and when uploading to localhost, I do see the 500mb/sec quoted capability (depending on physical hardware of the computer).

However, when uploading a file over the internet, you are subject to the bandwidth limitations of your ISP upload speed as well as the download speed of your server.

You report that a 10MB file takes ~80 seconds to upload to the server.  That's about 125KBps (or around 1 megabit/second) which seems fairly reasonable for a home/office ISP upload speed (depending on region of the world).

A good way to eliminate your home/office network performance from the troubleshooting equation would be to write a node.js script that uploads a file several times and calculates an average speed.  Run that test file on your local computer, then try again from a different server in the cloud.